# checkpoint package R - loading library not installed

Tags: r, reproducible-research

I'm trying to use `checkpoint` package which seems pretty simple. I installed checkpoint library and use the main function

```
checkpoint("yyyy-mm-dd")
```

After this, checkpoint just installed `dplyr`, which is what I expected ( it was the only library invoked in my code).
If I run `.libPaths` this is the expected result, that looks fine to me.

```
[1] "C:/Users/marco.fumagalli/Documents/.checkpoint/2018-11-11/lib/x86_64-w64-mingw32/3.5.0"
[2] "C:/Users/marco.fumagalli/Documents/.checkpoint/R-3.5.0"                                
[3] "C:/Users/MARCO~1.FUM/DOCUME~1/R/R-35~1.0/library"
```

Now I try to load `xgboost` library that is not installed in checkpoint directory ( I verified with `installed.packages(.libPaths()[1])[, "Package"]`).

From documentation

> checkpoint allows you to install packages locally as they existed on a
>   specific date from the corresponding snapshot (stored on the
>   checkpoint server) and it configures your R session to use only these
>   packages.

The problem is that R loaded `xgboost` library which isn't in the chheckpoint directory. It seems that R is loading this package from

```
"C:/Users/MARCO~1.FUM/DOCUME~1/R/R-35~1.0/library"
```

Thanks